# Not seeing column names when reading csv from s3 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, read-csv

I am using the following bit of code to read the iris dataset from an s3 bucket.

```
import pandas as pd
import s3fs

s3_path = 's3://h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/iris/iris.csv'

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)
with s3.open(s3_path, 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header = True)
```

However, the column names are just the contents of the first row of the dataset. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

The following changes are required:

1. s3_path should omit the `s3://`.
2. `iris.csv` is a file without header. In case you need a file with header then you should go for `iris_wheader.csv` file.
3. In `read_csv` header accepts boolean value

Your final code should look something like this

```
import s3fs
import pandas as pd

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=True)

with s3.open('h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv', 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    print(df.head())
```

Edit: You can directly read the file in pandas as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('s3://h2o-public-test-data/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv', header=0, storage_options={
    "anon": True
})
print(df.head())
```

You still need to install s3fs. Just that no need to open a file for accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html for all the parameters.

If you don't have a CSV with the column names, you can use the `names` parameter to specify the names you want. In that case, you do not need to set `header` to True.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, names=['yan', 'tan', 'tetherer', 'mether', 'pip'])
```